# Retrieve data from another table using index

Tags: python, pandas

I want to deal with biological data using python and pandas.

Table 1 is consist of name of protein pairs. XX, YY, ZZ and AA mean the name of protein.
Table 2 is consist of some data(values) of each proteins.

What I want to calculate is Pearson Correlation Coefficient(PCC) of each protein pairs that exist in Table 1, using the Data list of Table 2. It is a kind of database-like approach.

```
Table 1

Col1 Col2
 XX YY
 XX ZZ
 ZZ AA

Table 2

      XX YY ZZ AA BB CC ...
Data1 10 20 30 40 50 60 ...
Data2 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...
Data3 80 70 60 50 40 20 ...

Result

      PCC
XX_YY R1
XX_ZZ R2
ZZ_AA R3
```

R1 in the result table is the PCC value of protein XX and YY, in other words, the result of pearsonr([10, 11, 80], [20, 12, 70]). R2 and R3 will be pearsonr([10, 11, 80], [30, 13, 60]) and pearsonr([30, 13, 60], [40, 14, 50]) each.

I got an advice to use `combination` function before in this kind of work. It was very nice when calculating with all pairs, but in this case, I need to calculate only about the protein pairs which are in table 1, so it is difficult to use.

Is there any simple way to do this kind of work easily with pandas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through the rows of the first `DataFrame` (`df1`), select the relevant columns from `df2` and add the result with appropriate labels to a `dictionary`, which you can convert to a `Series` when done:

```
correlations = {}
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    correlations[row['col1' + '_' + row['col2']]] = df2.loc[:,row['col1']].corr(df2.loc[:, row['col2'], method='pearson')

result = pd.Series(correlations)
```

Comment: Thank you again Jansen! I am surprised when other people solve this kind of problem with a few lines of codes in python(But it is little difficult to understand because I am very new to python). If you don't mind, can you give me advice about some books or websites dealing with this kind of table works please?

Comment: Hi z991, I would in fact recommend the `pandas` docs for this library in particular http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/. They come  with plenty of examples in addition to up-to-date reference.

Comment: I have read 10 mins to pandas before, but I think I have to study more. I'd better follow examples in pandas docs for practice. Thank you very much Jansen.